# Processors supported by Raspbian

Tags: raspbian

I love working with Raspberry Pi, so i have decided to build my custom board but with different processors as Broadcom's processors are not available in the market. Can i find the list of supported processors for Raspbian operating system ? I want to design new board in which current Raspbian OS and all its libraries are supported. Is it possible to build custom board?

Comment: you got the raspberry pi processors, and there's a x86 distro available at raspberrypi.org ... of course, raspbian is based on debian - so ...

Comment: Raspberry pi processors r not available in the market. Even it's difficult to get raspberry pi board in the market as they r usually out of stock. So I wanted to make custom board that support raspbian os .

Comment: see [Will Raspbian work with non-Raspberry Pi systems? - Raspbian FAQ](https://raspbian.org/RaspbianFAQ#Will_Raspbian_work_with_non-Raspberry_Pi_systems.3F)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that raspbian.org and raspberrypi.org are different entities. The image files available on
raspberrypi.org are only legal to use with official Raspberry Pi. You can use everything from raspbian.org and the Linux kernel which everybody must distribute under GPLv2 to create your "pure" variant of Raspbian, as many companies do.

Secondly it is very difficult to get hold of the Raspberry Pi SoCs. For this reason the compute module was invented. This also circumvents some software licensing issues (mentioned above), especially regarding essential  Raspberry Pi firmware files.

For very serious projects, consider the element14 Customization Service. Minimum Order seems to be 5000 units (175 000 $?) but it seems very flexible and has endorsment of the Raspberry Pi founders.